# DataTables warning: table id=admin_table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-2

I am using jquery Datatables  and i am getting this error

> DataTables warning: table id=admin_table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

and from some plugins it's showing 304 error.

Comment: http 304 is not an error.  Besides that, how should any one could figure out what your problem is ...? There could be a lot of reasons, dataTables kindly suggest the most common causes.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome console, you can see the link on which datatable requests data, open that link in new tab and see if there is any error from the server side.

If you cannot see any link in console then right click and click Log XMLHttpRequests and then try again.